# silverstripe 4 has_many relationship giving errors

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

getting this error;

> [Emergency] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: has_many relation 
>   abc\def\ghi\Customer.OrderRegistrants references class Order which
>   doesn't exist

```
 private static $has_many = [
        'OrderRegistrants'      => 'Order.Registrant'
]
```

Comment: does the class `Order` exist? Does `Order` have a `$has_one` referencing this class?

Comment: @Isaac yes order class is there,  private static $has_one = [
        'Registrant'   => Customer::class,
]

Comment: What about the namespace of the `Order` class?

Comment: @Isaac nothing wrong with namespace, with has_one I can use 
private static $has_one = [
        'Order'           => Order::class,
    ];
even with has_many I can use 
private static $has_many = [
        'Orders'           => Order::class,
    ];
but cant use "ClassName.Field" ,

Comment: @Isaac I got the solution,  Robbie Averill made it, thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Order` has a namespace, you're not referencing it correctly. Try this:

```
private static $has_many = [
    'OrderRegistrants'      => Order::class . '.Registrant',
];
```

This will ensure that any imported (via `use My\Package\Order;` for example) namespaces for the `Order` class will be honoured. The way you've got it won't take any namespaces into account.